Why do I get 404 SpringBoot Errors?
I have seen many postings here on SO regarding 404 errors in SpringBoot Controllers, but I'm having the same issue and I can't find any solutions in the postings.
I'm using Intellij and created a SpringBoot 3 project using the built-in Intellij wizard and also, as a separate test, via a downloaded a "spring.io" project with only the Spring Web dependency. Neither of these works.
Using Java Version 17
I have an older 2.x SpringBoot project (I used for comparison only) that does work as expected, but I'm assuming the Intellij wizard and the spring.io setup would create a correctly-working 3.3.5 SpringBoot project. Thus, the problem must be elsewhere. I've compared the working SpringBoot project to the new non-working ones and cannot find the problem, that is, why the controller is returning 404.
Here are the files. Please let me know if you need any more detail or if you see the problem! Thanks.
Build type: WAR - Deploys to Tomcat 9.4.1 OK. Shows "Running".
POM.XML
Spring Dependencies:
<dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot Web Starter for RESTful web services -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot Actuator for monitoring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        

Spring Version from POM:
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.5</version> 
        <relativePath/> 
    </parent>       

Application.properties (in resources folder)
spring.application.name=te
server.servlet.context-path=/te  (have tried using both /te and blank for path)
server.port=8080

Both the Application class below and the Servlet Initializer class are in the package above the controllers class - in the root of the application.
Application Class
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TeApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TeApplication.class, args);
    }
}

Servlet Initializer
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(TeApplication.class);
    }

}

RestController Class --  localhost:8080/te/about -> Returns 404
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/te")
public class AboutController
{

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(AboutController.class);

    @GetMapping(value = "/about")
    public String aboutMessage()
    {
        return "Hello from About!";
    }
}

Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions where the mistake might reside.

server.* properties are useless if you are deploying the application to an external tomcat. The URL will become http://localhost:8080/<name-of-war>/te/about. Next to that Spring Boot 3.x requires at least Tomcat 10.x as that is for JakartaEE, Tomcat 9 is for JavaEE.

Also, beware about trailing slash breaking change in SB 3: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-3-url-matching

Thank you!!! This was the answer: Tomcat 10. Can't believe I missed that basic requirement. Appreciate your second set of eyes. :)
